# Is it possible to set timeout for a thread group?

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread group with few HTTP requests in it. I will be running few hundreds or thousands of threads. I would like to set the timeout for the threadgroup, so it would timeout when it exceeds a given time.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you say timeout for ThreadGroup - do you mean duration of the test? that is, you want the test for particular duration? If yes, you can set the duration in the Thread Group config.

[image]

If you mean, individual HTTP requests samplers to timeout after specific duration, then `HTTP Requests Default` is the best place to set that.

You can override that in the specific sampler as well.

[image]

Comment: I would be running few thousands of threads. My understanding is that, if I use the duration, then it would just stop the test after running for that particular time. If I add the timeout in a http request default, then it would be applicable to only that sampler. But I want to timeout the threadgroup if the server is loaded and takes a long time to return results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) like:

1. Add JSR223 Assertion somewhere in your Test Plan (make sure that it won't be executed too often)
2. Use the following code in the "Script" area (example code which will fail the current sampler and stop the test if Thread Group duration exceeds 5 seconds):

   ```
   def testStart = Long.parseLong(vars.get("TESTSTART.MS"))
   def now = System.currentTimeMillis()

   if ((now - testStart) >= 5000) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Thread group duration exceeded 5000 ms")
       SampleResult.setStopTest(true)
   }
   ```

Demo:

[image: JSR223 Assertion Example]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more detailed explanation on how setting pass/fail criteria for JMeter tests.

Comment: I tried to test this one by looping the http sampler with a wrong value so it would loop forever. I had added the JSR223 Assertion below the sampler. But looks like it would execute the assertion only when it exits the loop. can you tell me when would the assertion get executes in a thread?

Comment: Assertions obey the [scoping rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so if you added the assertion as a child of a sampler - it will be executed after each sampler

Answer (score -1):

Setting Response timeout value in the sampler[image]

Comment: This won't help me since this is restricted to a sampler. I want the timeout when the whole thread takes time when i use thousands of threads